# Binary 0000 to FFFF using C

Tags: c, binary

I am trying to program using C to write binary data to a .bin file and just iterate through to write from 0000 to FFFF. I figured I would use fopen with a 'wb' tag and then be able to write binary data but I'm unsure how to iterate from 0000 to FFFF using C. Thanks for any help.

Here's my code now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 FILE *f = fopen("binary.bin", "wb");
 unsigned long i;

 //if(f == NULL) { ...error handling... }

 for(i = 0x0000; i <= 0xFFFF; i++){
  // Write something to the file, e.g. the 16-bit (2 byte) value of "i"
  unsigned short someData = i;
  fwrite(&someData, 1, 2, f);
 }

 fclose(f);
 return 0;
 //printf("Hello World\n");
 getchar();
}
```

This will output 00 00 01 00 02 00 ...

Here's my question now. Isn't this supposed to read out 00 00 00 01 00 02...Shouldn't there be an extra '00' at the beginning?

Also, I've been trying to see how could I copy it and extend it therefore making it 0000 0000 0001 0001 etc?
[Update: I just copied the fwrite line and did it again and it solved this problem]

Comment: "unsure how to iterate"  What -- specifically -- were you unsure about?  Could you add your specific issues to this question?

Comment: It's helpful if you provided a relevant snippet so that we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Your machine is little-endian, most are.  Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_endian

Comment: As nobugz pointed out: your CPU probably is little-endian, i.e. if you store a 16-bit value, first (at lower address) the LSByte is written (0x01 for value 1), than the MSByte (0x00 for value 1)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simple example of writing some binary numbers to a file.

```
FILE *f = fopen("yourfile", "wb");

if(f == NULL) { ...error handling... }

for(unsigned long i = 0x0000; i <= 0xFFFF; ++i)
{
    // Write something to the file, e.g. the 16-bit (2 byte) value of "i"
    unsigned short someData = i;
    fwrite(&someData, 1, 2, f);
}

fclose(f);
```

Note that the variable `i` here must be bigger than 16-bit so that it does not wrap around (see my comments on the other answers). The `long` type guarantees a size of at least 32 bit.

Comment: thanks for this. i still ran into some problems. i've edited the original question.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i = 0x0000; i <= 0xffff; ++i)
```

Comment: Make sure the type of `i` is bigger than an `unsigned short` (e.g. `int` or `unsigned int`).  When you come to write it out to your binary file, you'll have to cast back to `unsigned short`.

Comment: Tony - Regarding the edit - wouldn't unsigned short overflow to 0? Plus, I am not sure this would be valid ANSI C.

Comment: @Ofir: Definitely, the current implementation is an endless loop.

Comment: Same thing here. 0xFFFF++ would wrap around to 0, producing an infinite loop.

Comment: Assuming a 16-bit short, a short is always less than or equal to 0xFFFF, and `i <= 0xffff` will always evaluate to 1.

Comment: @nobugz: `int` will only work on platforms which define it as more than 16 bit. As of the standard, the int type has a minimum of 16 bits, so this solution is not cross-platform.

Comment: Actually... Assuming a 16-bit short 0xFFFF is -1 (two's compliment). In which case this loop would never execute. Make sure your counter is unsigned, and either stop short of 0xFFFF and do the last element outside the loop, or ensure that your counter is larger than 16 bits.

Answer (score 3):

To loop from `0` to `0xffff`, both inclusive, you do:

```
for (i=0; i <= 0xffff; ++i)
```

Now, the first interesting question is, what should be the type of `i`?  In C, an `unsigned int` is guaranteed to hold values in the range `[0, 0xffff]`, which means that `i <= 0xffff` will always be true for `unsigned int i;` if `UINT_MAX` is `0xffff`.  so `i` can't be a type of size smaller or equal to `unsigned int`.  `long` or `unsigned long` is the smallest type guaranteed to be able to store `0xffff + 1` portably.  So, we need `i` to be of `unsigned long` or `long` type.  In C99, you can make things easier by including `stdint.h` and then using `uint32_t` type.

The second interesting question is, what do you want to write?  Is your file's layout going to be:

```
00 00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07
...
FF F8 FF F9 FF FA FF FB FF FC FF FD FF FE FF FF
```

or do you want to write values to a file using your favorite data type above and then be able to read them back again quickly?  For example, if `int` is 32 bits, and your system is little-endian, writing those values will give you a file such as:

```
00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 ...
```

If you want the first, you have to make sure you write two bytes per number, in the correct order, and that endian-ness of your OS doesn't affect the output.  The easiest way to do so is probably something like this:

```
for (i=0; i <= 0xff; ++i) {
    unsigned char values[2];
    values[0] = (i & 0xff00) >> 8;
    values[1] = i & 0xff; 
    fwrite(values, 1, 2, fp); 
}
```

If you want the second, your life is easier, particularly if you don't care about endian-ness:

```
for (i=0; i <= 0xff; ++i) {
    fwrite(&i, sizeof i, 1, fp);
}
```

will write your values so you can read them back on the same system with the same kind of variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0x0000; i <= 0xFFFF; ++i)
```

Comment: for(unsigned short i = 0;...)

Comment: Using `<` will miss out `0xFFFF`.  Be careful using `unsigned short` and `i <= 0xFFFF` though, as `i` will always match the condition and your loop will continue forever (`0xFFFF + 1 = 0`).

Comment: Good point, but there is no reason to use a 16bit iterator, it is only important to write 16 bits at a time.

Comment: This kind of lacks a type for the i variable.

Comment: @Paul Stephenson: Wrote almost exactly the same comment, now deleted :)

Comment: If `i` is 16-bit, this would be an infinite loop (0xFFFF++ wraps around to 0). So `i` must be at least 32-bit!

Answer (score 0):

To control the *Endianess* of your output, you will have to write the bytes (octets) yourself:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; // Same as 0x0000
     i <= 0xFFFF;
     ++i)
{
  unsigned char c;
  c = i / 256; // In Big Endian, output the Most Significant Byte (MSB) first.
  fputc(/*...*/);
  c = i % 256;
  fputc(/*...*/);
}
```

This is a preferred method when the file must be Big Endian.  This will ensure the byte ordering regardless of the processor's endianess.  This can be adjusted to output in Little Endican as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method for portably writing bytes in big endian style: check out `htons` and `htonl` (and their inverses).

These convert from whatever format your machine uses (Intel chips are little endian, as several people have pointed out) into "Network" order (big endian). `htons` does this in 16-bit words; `htonl` in 32-bit words. As an added benefit, if your program is on a Big Endian machine, these compile out to no-ops. They're defined in `<arpa/inet.h>` or `<netinet/in.h>`, depending on the system.

BSD (and Linux) also provide(s) a collection of routines named things like `htobe16` (host to big endian 16-bit) in `<endian.h>`.

These also help save the overhead of writing one byte at a time.

If you *do* want to extract high bytes / low bytes yourself, you probably should also use bit masking to do it. Your compiler might be smart enough to convert divide/modulo into bit masks, but if it doesn't, you'll have deplorable performance (division is *slow*).

```
{
  unsigned int x = 0xdead;
  unsigned char hi = (x & 0xff00) >> 8;
  unsigned char lo = (x & 0x00ff);
}
{
  unsigned long int x = 0xdeadbeef;
  unsigned char by0 = (x & 0xff000000) >> 24;
  unsigned char by1 = (x & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
  unsigned char by2 = (x & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
  unsigned char by3 = (x & 0x000000ff);
}
```

(It looks like `gcc` is smart enough to do the optimization out of the division, though… nice.)